# Why Recursive Generator doesn't work in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a recursive generator in Python, but I'm doing something wrong. Here's a minimal example. I would expect the function f() to return an iterable that would give me all the positive numbers >= n.

```
>>> def f(n):
...     yield n
...     if n>0:
...         f(n-1)
... 
>>> [ i for i in f(30) ]
[30]
```

Why is the iteration stopping after the first number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `f(n-1)` is again a generator, which can be consumed only with the `next` protocol. If you are using Python 3.3+, you can use `yield from`, like this

```
def f(n):
    yield n
    if n > 0:
        yield from f(n-1)

print(list(f(10)))
# [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

If you want to fix with out `yield from` or using a Python version which doesn't have `yield from`, then you have to manually iterate and yield like this

```
def f(n):
    yield n
    if n > 0:
        for item in f(n-1):
            yield item
```

Comment: somewhat inefficient though... what use recursion in the first place? kinda of defeats the point of the generator, no?

Comment: The minimal case I posted was proof of concept. The real problem I'm trying to solve is more complex, but not fundamentally different in the way the recursive call is made.

Comment: I think question was about language feature, not about efficiency in this case. Not always you can it will be simple arithmetic, you can use this for things like traversing tree

Comment: @mojo You can use the alternate solution in the answer :) Your question had Python 3.x tag, so I assumed the latest Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is doing:

```
return a generator that generates "n"
call function f(n-1) which returns a generator
throw that inner generator away, never use it
quit
```

Comment: @mojo Your posted example code doesn't work, you asked why, and I'm explaining what it's doing to show why it doesn't work. I don't follow what you mean about 'not the actual problem'.

Comment: I'm sorry. You're correct. I can't change my vote, though, unless the answer is edited. Do you want to make some superficial change so that I can change it?